# UserInterface slow when zxing is used

Tags: ios, ipad, zxing

I have UI which contains a small tableview, a zxing window, submit button.
Table contains names scanned by zxing. Table has swipe to delete.
On click of submit alertView shows up asking whether to sync users.

Both above actions a slow. Alertview shows up and do not take tap of 15secs.
Same way with swipe to delete. After swipe it take 10 sec to swipe.
This happens on ios6 iPad air. But it works smoothly in ios7 iPad mini.

Here is code for adding zxing window.

```
widController =
    [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:NO OneDMode:NO showLicense:NO];
    NSMutableSet *readers = [[NSMutableSet alloc ] init];
    MultiFormatReader* reader = [[MultiFormatReader alloc] init];
    [readers addObject:reader];
    widController.readers = readers;
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    widController.soundToPlay =
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"beep-beep" ofType:@"aiff"] isDirectory:NO];
//    widController.view.frame = CGRectMake(95, 245, 338, 338);
    widController.view.frame = CGRectMake(45, 155, 338, 338);

    [self.view_box addSubview:widController.view];
```

Comment: Use Instruments and profile your app to see what's using up the CPU.

Comment: FYI - there's an easier way to get a URL for a file in your resource bundle: `widController.soundToPlay = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"beep-beep" withExtension:@"aiff"];`